# predict nominal values in SMO

Tags: machine-learning, weka, svm

I'm using SMO in classify nominal values. After I build the classifier I need to predict the class for instance but classifyInstance (weka.classifiers.Classifier.classifyInstance) return only double number.

How can I use the double number to get the original nominal class?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are calling the weka classes in your Java code, you'll need to know that internally, Weka handles all values as doubles.

When you create the `Attribute`, you pass it an array of strings that lists the possible nominal values. The `double` that classification returns is the index of the chosen attribute in the original array. So if you had code that looked like this:

```
String[] attributeValues = {"a", "b", "c"};
Attribute a = new Attribute("attributeName", attributeValues);
```

and `classifyInstance()` returned 2, then the class it chose would be `attributeValues[2]` or "c".